# "One-Off" Editable field Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am creating an intranet with Django and I would like to make certain unique parts of the site editable (welcome message, mission statement, etc) from the built-in admin interface.

I currently have a model that houses these "unique" sections:

```
def Section(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

then I make explicit template calls that pulls out the appropriate section.  This works, but an admin could add more content to this model that wont show up and this could be confusing and is undesirable.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a pluggable Django CMS app? I would suggest [django-cms](http://www.django-cms.org) or [django-flatblocks](http://www.github.com/zerok/django-flatblocks). Both can do what you are looking for. Flatblocks is a simpler system and quick to implementation while django-cms is more involved (comparatively) but has a lot more features/ functionality.

Comment: ... i think for this purpose an app like django-flatblocks (https://github.com/zerok/django-flatblocks) should be sufficient.

Comment: Have never seen that app before but really like how simple it is. django-cms contains a similar functionality but does take some time to setup and get comfortable using.